# how to get the index/ order of a defect in the Backlog, Rally Rest API C#

Tags: c#, rally

Task:
List all defects in the backlog of a project by their rank/index.

Here is my code:

```
var myRequest = new Request()
    {
        ArtifactName = "defect",
        Limit = 2000,
        Query = new Query("Project.OID", Query.Operator.Equals, MyDefectProjectOID),
        Fetch = new List<string>() { "true" }
    };


    QueryResult queryMyResult = api.Query(myRequest);
```

**Question:**

1) How do I get the result set back in the order my users have organised them in Rally.

2) Is there a value on the defect item that tells me the rank/index (for example the Task item has a TaskIndex property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Order by the DragAndDropRank field, ASC.

2) As long as you fetch DragAndDropRank as well that's your rank value.  It's encoded as a string which is sortable in client code.  The overall numeric index will be its index in your result set.

Another quick note- rather than specifying a query on Project.ObjectID to control scoping, you can just set the Project, ProjectScopeUp and ProjectScopeDown values:

```
Project = "/project/" + MyDefectProjectOID,
ProjectScopeUp = false,
ProjectScopeDown = false
```